# Is there a way to access the React-Native Context from module that is not part of React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React context that manages authentication and provides an Axios client.  However that Axios client needs to be reconfigured everytime there's a new token.

I'm also using expo-sqlite which has issues with database locking when the application restarts and sometimes when the object gets reloaded.

So I was wondering if there's a way for a plain module to access the React Context to get an item from the context in React-Native.

I was thinking of Portals but that's talking about DOM

Answer (score 0):

From React documentation:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

In your case is better to use [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) - fast sync key-value storage.

If I understand correctly you receive auth tokens as a result of an HTTP request, and if you know you need to update it you can write it to mmkv.